# Issue with aligning bars with x axis and making the bar width fit to a range

Tags: charts, android-graphview

I'm trying to create a Bar chart using GraphView to display a count against ranges. The way I input data is GraphViewData(1, 0), GraphViewData(2, 5),GraphViewData(3, 7) and likewise. However each of these x values represents a range as 0 to 1, 1 to 2......., 23 to 24. How can I achieve this?

This is how my chart appears now. (Pleas note that even this doesn't get properly aligned with x axis. for instance the bar at (18.6, 8) must actually be (20, 8)). Thanks in advance.

[image: Chart with problematic x axis]

Comment: Have you solved the issue?.

Comment: Not exactly. However, switching to line chart seemed to work, and I decided to put a small note regarding the actual representation (as 0 represents 0 to 1, 1 represents 1 to 2, etc)